# Youtube Video crash app iOS (Received memory warning)

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks, youtube

I am trying to play youtube videos in my app..
and it works fine.. but total are 7 in numbers and when I play one by one all the videos. and plays the fifth `video`. It `crash` my app with memory waring

```
2013-03-07 12:31:01.167 Magazine[3015:707] Received memory warning.
```

why this error is coming on particular video.. is this because of the memory low or some other reason.I have embedded the youtube in my app . please check the code.
why this memory issue is coming for the particular `youtube` video.
I think memory get full when I play videos on my iPad1 ..how to release it from memory...

```
UIWebView *youtube_player=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, Yposition +k*Height, 400, Height)];
        youtube_player.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        youtube_player.opaque = NO;
        youtube_player.delegate=self;
        NSString *videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                               <html>\
                               <head>\
                               <style type=\"text/css\">\
                               iframe {position:absolute; top:50%%; margin-top:-130px;}\
                               body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}\
                               </style>\
                               </head>\
                               <body>\
                               <iframe width=\"100%%\" height=\"240px\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
                               </body>\
                               </html>", [[videos objectAtIndex:k] _video_path]];
        youtube_player.scrollView.scrollEnabled=NO;
        UIScrollView *scrollView = [youtube_player.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
        scrollView.delegate = self;
        [youtube_player loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];
        youtube_player.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;

        [mMoviePlayersArray_por addObject:youtube_player];
```

Comment: how are you playing the video one aftr the othr? are you clearing the webview aftr ending each video? i mean a blank page..

Comment: no how to do that .,...and where

Comment: first let me know how u r playing one aftr other..? does user plays it manually or u play it through code automatically..?

Comment: manually ..suppose i click first ..then second..then third